# Laravel 8 migrate does not found migrations table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to migrate my tables into laravel database, but *artisan* is not finding *migrations* table.

I have tried, creating migrations manually importing the structure from other laravel installation, but the error continues

I also have created  migrations table using php aritsan migration:install comand

But I have noted that when I run php artisan migrate, the migrations table is being deleted and then show the error that the table does not exists.

See complete error bellow

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Loading stored database schema: /path/to/laravel/project/database/schema/mysql-schema.sql
Loaded stored database schema. (15.32ms)

Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test_db.migrations' doesn't exist (SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕ 

    +31 vendor frames 
32  artisan:37
    Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Technical details:

- Laravel 8.6
- MariaDB 15.1

Comment: Does the migration table exist in your database?

Comment: Yes, but when I run php artisan migrate is eliminated and show the error.

Comment: can you also show the first migration code?

Comment: Get rid of the schema dump would be step 1

Comment: This was the first that I used, because is suggested in the documentation, but not worked. It need to be done in the following order: 1. php artisan migrate:install, 2. php artisan schema:dump, 3. php artisan migrate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with dropping and wiping:
Can you please run `php artisan db:wipe` and after that run artisan migrate and let me know the result?